# How to disabled/enabled multiple checkbox on 1 form jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button

it has 2 separate radiogroup

I want to enable button checkbox with class="terlambat0" when radiobutton with class="hadir0" is clicked and how can I make it disable again when the others radiobutton (class="sakit0" or "izin0" or "absen0") is clicked?

and enable checkbox "terlambat1" when "hadir1" is clicked and make it disable again when "sakit1" or "izin1" or "absen1" is clicked?

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="col-sm-1 text-center">No.</th>
        <th class="col-sm-5">Nama</th>
        <th class="col-sm-4">Kehadiran</th>
        <th class="col-sm-2">Keterangan</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <fieldset id="kehadiran1">
        <td class="text-center">1</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input class="hadir0" type="radio" value="Hadir" name="kehadiran[0]">Hadir</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input class="sakit0" type="radio" value="Sakit" name="kehadiran[0]">Sakit</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input class="absen0" type="radio" value="Absen" name="kehadiran[0]">Absen</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input class="izin0" type="radio" value="Izin" name="kehadiran[0]">Izin</label>
        </td>
        <td><label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="terlambat0" type="checkbox" value="Terlambat" name="keterangan[0]" disabled="true"> Terlambat</label></td>
        </fieldset>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <fieldset id="kehadiran2">
        <td class="text-center">2</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input class="hadir1" type="radio" value="Hadir" name="kehadiran[1]">Hadir</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input class="sakit1" type="radio" value="Sakit" name="kehadiran[1]">Sakit</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input class="absen1" type="radio" value="Absen" name="kehadiran[1]">Absen</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input class="izin1" type="radio" value="Izin" name="kehadiran[1]">Izin</label>
        </td>
        <td><label class="checkbox-inline"><input class="terlambat1" type="checkbox" value="Terlambat" name="keterangan[1]" disabled="true"> Terlambat</label></td>
        </fieldset>
    </tr>
</tbody></table><input class="btn btn-link" type="submit" name="submit" id="hadirSemua" value="Hadir Semua">
```

jquery: when the button with id="hadirSemua" is clicked, all radio button with class="hadir" will be on, and of course all checkbox with class="terlambat" will be enable

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#hadirSemua").attr("data-type", "check");
    $("#hadirSemua").click(function() 
    {
        if ($("#hadirSemua").attr("data-type") === "check") 
        {
            for($i=0; $i<2; $i++)
            {
                $(".terlambat"+$i).prop("disabled", false);
                $(".hadir"+$i).prop("checked", true);
            }
        } 
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class doesn't have to be unique so I am removing the numeric values of class.

> when the button with id="hadirSemua" is clicked, all radio button with class="hadir" will be on, and of course all checkbox with class="terlambat" will be enable

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#hadirSemua").click(function() {
      $(".terlambat").prop("disabled", false);
      $(".hadir").prop("checked", true);
    })
});
```

> I want to enable button checkbox with class="terlambat0" when radiobutton with class="hadir0" is clicked and how can I make it disable again when the others radiobutton (class="sakit0" or "izin0" or "absen0") is clicked? and enable checkbox "terlambat1" when "hadir1" is clicked and make it disable again when "sakit1" or "izin1" or "absen1" is clicked?

```
$(".hadir").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".terlambat").prop("disabled", false);
  }
})

$(".sakit,.absen,.izin").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    //if other radio is called, I am unchecking the checkbox. you can remove it if you want to.
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".terlambat").prop('checked', false).prop("disabled", true);
  }
})
```

**Snippet**

```js
$("#hadirSemua").click(function() {
  $(".terlambat").prop("disabled", false);
  $(".hadir").prop("checked", true);
})


$(".hadir").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".terlambat").prop("disabled", false);
  }
})


$(".sakit,.absen,.izin").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    //if other radio is called, I am unchecking the checkbox. you can remove it if you want to.
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".terlambat").prop('checked', false).prop("disabled", true);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-sm-1 text-center">No.</th>
      <th class="col-sm-5">Nama</th>
      <th class="col-sm-4">Kehadiran</th>
      <th class="col-sm-2">Keterangan</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <fieldset id="kehadiran1">
        <td class="text-center">1</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input class="hadir" type="radio" value="Hadir" name="kehadiran[0]">Hadir</label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input class="sakit" type="radio" value="Sakit" name="kehadiran[0]">Sakit</label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input class="absen" type="radio" value="Absen" name="kehadiran[0]">Absen</label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input class="izin" type="radio" value="Izin" name="kehadiran[0]">Izin</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input class="terlambat" type="checkbox" value="Terlambat" name="keterangan[0]" disabled="true"> Terlambat</label>
        </td>
      </fieldset>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <fieldset id="kehadiran2">
        <td class="text-center">2</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input class="hadir" type="radio" value="Hadir" name="kehadiran[1]">Hadir</label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input class="sakit" type="radio" value="Sakit" name="kehadiran[1]">Sakit</label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input class="absen" type="radio" value="Absen" name="kehadiran[1]">Absen</label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input class="izin" type="radio" value="Izin" name="kehadiran[1]">Izin</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input class="terlambat" type="checkbox" value="Terlambat" name="keterangan[1]" disabled="true"> Terlambat</label>
        </td>
      </fieldset>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input class="btn btn-link" type="submit" name="submit" id="hadirSemua" value="Hadir Semua">
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your actual markup:

- You can fire an event on change of the radio buttons
- And if the value of the selected one is "Hadir" then activate, other value will disable the checkbox.
- With your Button just trigger the click fo the "Hadir" elements

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){
  var v = $(this).val(),
      c = $(this).parents('fieldset').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
  c.prop('disabled',v !== "Hadir" )
})
$('#hadirSemua').on('click',function(){
  $('input[value="Hadir"]').click()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="col-sm-1 text-center">No.</th>
    <th class="col-sm-5">Nama</th>
    <th class="col-sm-4">Kehadiran</th>
    <th class="col-sm-2">Keterangan</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <fieldset id="kehadiran1">
      <td class="text-center">1</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input class="hadir0" type="radio" value="Hadir" name="kehadiran[0]">Hadir</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input class="sakit0" type="radio" value="Sakit" name="kehadiran[0]">Sakit</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input class="absen0" type="radio" value="Absen" name="kehadiran[0]">Absen</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input class="izin0" type="radio" value="Izin" name="kehadiran[0]">Izin</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input class="terlambat0" type="checkbox" value="Terlambat" name="keterangan[0]" disabled="true">Terlambat</label>
      </td>
    </fieldset>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <fieldset id="kehadiran2">
      <td class="text-center">2</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input class="hadir1" type="radio" value="Hadir" name="kehadiran[1]">Hadir</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input class="sakit1" type="radio" value="Sakit" name="kehadiran[1]">Sakit</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input class="absen1" type="radio" value="Absen" name="kehadiran[1]">Absen</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input class="izin1" type="radio" value="Izin" name="kehadiran[1]">Izin</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input class="terlambat1" type="checkbox" value="Terlambat" name="keterangan[1]" disabled="true">Terlambat</label>
      </td>
    </fieldset>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input class="btn btn-link" type="submit" name="submit" id="hadirSemua" value="Hadir Semua">
```

Comment: thank you very much. I'm not familiar with jquery, its really different to php, java, or c language.

Comment: np mate glad to help U @ReinhardArmstrong